# Why I can't define a function in the `lib` scope?

Tags: crystal-lang

For example, this code won't compile

```
def double
  x * x
end

lib LibC
  # Error
  def double
    x * x
  end
end
```

I know that we can use module, but we can't have the same LibC name as both module and lib

```
lib LibC

end

module LibC
  def double
    x * x
  end
end
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Why is this a problem for you? :)

`lib` defines a binding to an external library. Technically it does so by defining function signatures of external symbols that the linker will resolve. Additionally it allows the definition of structs with C ABI semantics, enums for mapping a series of constants used in an external library interface into a useful grouping and aliases to make it easier to map Crystal types to C types in a binding definition.

When binding a library, this lowlevel `lib` definition should never be the end result for the user of your binding! Instead you should define at least a thin wrapper transforming the external API into a more idiomatic Crystal version.

So say we're writing a binding to the fictional libsaucepan you would start out with a `lib` definition, maybe like this:

```
@[Link("saucepan")]
lib LibSaucepan
  alias Pan = Void*
  fun aquire : Pan
  fun add_water(pan : Pan, ml : LibC::Int)
  fun cook(pan : Pan)
  fun is_done(pan : Pan) : LibC::Int
end
```

You wouldn't stop here, but maybe create a class that wraps the API:

```
class Saucepan
  def initialize
    @pan = LibSaucepan.aquire
  end

  def add_water(ml : Int)
     LibSaucepan.add_water(@pan, LibC::Int.new(ml))
  end

  def done?
    LibSaucepan.is_done(@pan) == 1
  end

  def cook
    LibSaucepan.cook(@pan)

    until done?
      sleep 1
    end
  end

  def heat_water(ml : Int)
    add_water(ml)
    cook
  end
end
```

This wrapper is where you would put any helper methods :)

Comment: I just curious if we can put a function definition in the `LibC` "namespace" because we can put constant variable there, but apparently there's no solution for this problem. Thank you for your explanation